# "+=" operator not working when modifying .json in variable (Python)

Tags: python, json

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to store data in a .json, and then access and modify it through Python. Currently I'm having an issue where I can't modify the data if I try to use a variable instead of *directly* modifying it. It works fine if it's not in a variable, or if I'm just reading the information, or if it's not in a function.

```
import json

with open('testprog.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    x = int(data['valueOne']) 
    def test():
        x += 1
#VSC tells me this variable is not defined. 
#If I swap the variable for “int(data[‘valueOne’])” it works.
        f.seek(0)
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
        f.truncate()

    test()
    print("New first value is: "+str(data['valueOne']))
```

.json:

```
{
    "valueOne": 10,
    "valueTwo": 5,
    "valueThree": 8
}
```

Comment: `x += 1` doesn't change `data` at all, you're just reassigning the local variable `x`.

Comment: `data['valueOne'] = x` after modification.

Comment: i don't understand why you would expect `x += 1` to modify data. it seems to be a reach at best, wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the value associated with the key *valueOne* is a string. Therefore you could do this:

```
data['valueOne'] = str(int(data['valueOne']) + 1)
```

Comment: It's a pity that when an Answer is downvoted, there's no obligation to explain the reasoning